# Equivalent of curl "--path-as-is" in C# WebClient/WebRequest

Tags: c#, curl, webclient, webrequest, system.net.httpwebrequest

The argument `--path-as-is` in CURL by definition sends the request with the URL path as is, without squashing (Do not squash .. sequences in URL path).

How can I achieve the same behavior in C# using either WebClient or WebRequest?

Comment: Could you please add an example (edit the post please) of the behavior in curl and currently in c#?